# Coordinates with trigonometric ratios

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is possible to define coordinates using trigonometric ratios with the construction of a geometric figure, as in the attached example but it does not work for me.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,3);
    \draw (0,0) -- ({cos(30)},{tan(45)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `({cos(30)},{tan(45)});` (you have to protect the inner parentheses by wrapping the x and y coordinate in braces).

Comment: unfortunately the segment does not produce.

Comment: @SamuelDiaz: Are you saying that Henri Menke's suggestion did not work for you? Seems to work fine for me, so please elaborate if it did not work for you.

Comment: Correct, my code had an error, it works. thanks to @Henri Menke and Peter Grill

Comment: @HenriMenke Care to write up an answer?

Comment: @Troy It's actually a duplicate.